# Can a spouse of a Chinese citizen somehow visit China visa-free?

Tags: visas, china, eu-citizens, spouses

I'm an EU citizen and I'm married to a Chinese woman. Currently we live in the UK, and my wife wants go back home to see her family almost every year. Each time when we travel there, I need to apply for a visa. On the other hand, if we want to travel around Europe, she does not need a visa, as I hold a Schengen passport.

I wonder if there's something similar in China which allows me to enter China to travel around with my wife without a visa.

Comment: She's using her article 10 residence card to exempt her from the visa requirement, isn't she?  So she still needs the passport plus the residence card.  I think your best bet will be to get a long-term visa, if that's possible.  Visa-free travel seems very unlikely.  If your wife didn't have an article 10 residence card, she'd also need a visa to enter the Schengen area.

Comment: Actually, her not needing a visa is related to your very specific status as an EU citizen in the UK (and she does need a special document, her residence card, to enter EU countries). In all other cases (spouse of a British citizen in the UK, spouse of an EU citizen - even from a Schengen country - living outside the EU), Chinese citizens do need a visa. Presumably, China has something similar for *residents* but being completely exempt from any special requirement is very unlikely.

Comment: What visa type do you get when you go to China?  L?  Q2?  Other?

Comment: @phoog I don't remember, but I think usually I got Q2. I think when we visited China first time I got L.

Comment: @Relaxed I'm not sure, when we went to Europe first time after we got married, she didn't have residence card, she had only her passport with valid UK visa and our marriage certificate. But it is irrelevant.

Comment: I assume 72 hours or whatever, in one of a few big cities, on route to another country, isn't sufficient? Related question: http://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/76737/why-do-many-countries-in-the-world-still-require-citizens-of-states-with-a-high

Comment: @AndrewGrimm I'm familiar with 72h and 144h visas, but it is not what i'm looking for. I'm looking for something which allows us to travel around.

Comment: @user902383 how did you travel to Europe the first time?  No air carrier should have let her on the plane without a visa.

Comment: @user902383 Without any fuss? AFAIK, a visa is still required but it's true that if you make it to the border and have sufficient documentation, you might still be let in. I wrote a lengthy discussion of this situation in http://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/48970/does-a-non-eu-spouse-of-a-uk-national-need-a-visa-to-visit-the-schengen-area It's kind of relevant because it would dispel the confusion that led to your question: Having a Schengen passport (EU actually) does not generally exempt your wife from the visa requirement anywhere in the EU.

Comment: @Relaxed You are right, I'm not sure what i was thinking about. I said she have visa, but i realised it was UK residence card for EEA family member. And when we travel first time, it wasn't without fuss. When we entered Schengen zone, she spend at least 30 minutes on border control, as they didn't know what to do with her, and finally they let us in.

Comment: Apparently there is a longer multi-entry visa available for you [as per this site](https://www.travelchinaguide.com/embassy/visa/family-visit-permit.htm) - have you tried this approach?

Comment: @BurhanKhalid That is for foreigners with immediate family living in China. OP's wife is not living in China, and his in-laws would not count as immediate family.

Comment: I could add more detail, but I have been able to get a 10 year 120 day entry Q2 visa. The family member must be a current resident of China. As per consulate website: "Family members" refers to spouses, parents, sons, daughters, spouses of sons or daughters, brothers, sisters, grandparents, grandsons, granddaughters and parents-in-law."

Answer (score 3):

**To the best of my knowledge there is no such thing.**

While you can visit China visa-free either

- for [transit](http://www.flyertalk.com/forum/china/708095-china-24-72-144-hour-transit-without-visa-twov-rules-master-thread.html) within [24 hours](https://www.lonelyplanet.com/thorntree/forums/asia-north-east-asia/china/confusion-with-china-24h-visa-free-transit)
- under the [72/144 hour visa-free transit regime](https://travel.stackexchange.com/a/60643/32134) in some cities
- with a [tour for the Pearl river delta](https://travel.stackexchange.com/a/78652/32134) or
- to [special economic zones](https://travel.stackexchange.com/a/78652/32134),

this is not related to your status as a spouse of a Chinese national and you have made clear in comments that this not what you are looking for.

Then, for a visit you need a visa, either as a [tourist (L)](https://www.travelchinaguide.com/embassy/visa/tourist.htm) or [family reunion (Q)](https://www.travelchinaguide.com/embassy/visa/family-reunion.htm). User @BurhanKhalid also pointed out [this sort of residence permit](https://www.travelchinaguide.com/embassy/visa/family-visit-permit.htm) for family but as I read it that is not much use to you as it would need to be renewed annually and still is some sort of a visa.

Finally do note that, as has been pointed out in [comments](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/77029/can-a-spouse-of-a-chinese-citizen-somehow-visit-china-visa-free#comment169803_77029),

> her not needing a visa is related to your very specific status as an EU citizen in the UK (and she does need a special document, her residence card, to enter EU countries). In all other cases (spouse of a British citizen in the UK, spouse of an EU citizen - even from a Schengen country - living outside the EU), Chinese citizens do need a visa.